# Creating temp table in Vertica

Tags: sql, temp-tables, vertica

want to create a temp table in vertica containing lat, lng and restaurant_name

I am writing the code as below but it throws an error:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE geo_raw  (
lat float, 
lng float,
resto_name varchar) on commit PRESERVE rows

INSERT INTO geo_raw (lat, lng, resto_name)
VALUES (12.345, 12.3555, 'abc')

select * from geo_raw
```

The error is : 
ERROR
explain-plan-failed

> Syntax error at or near "float" around line 4:

Can someone please help ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can try `varchar (64)` instead of `varchar `

Comment: @D-Shih it still throws the same error.

Comment: Hi Nimish - running exactly your CREATE TABLE statement - with a semicolon at the end - works perfectly if I use vsql. What SQL client are you using?

Comment: Be sure to **exactly** cut and paste you commands and the error.

Comment: Same as @mauro, this script works fine on Vertica 8.1.1.0. Which version of Vertica are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the syntax once semi-colons are added to the end of each statement. Here's it working on a Vertica v9.0.1-3 system:

```
dbadmin=> CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE geo_raw  (
dbadmin(> lat float, 
dbadmin(> lng float,
dbadmin(> resto_name varchar) on commit PRESERVE rows;
CREATE TABLE
dbadmin=> INSERT INTO geo_raw (lat, lng, resto_name)
dbadmin-> VALUES (12.345, 12.3555, 'abc');
 OUTPUT 
--------
      1
(1 row)

dbadmin=> select * from geo_raw;
  lat   |   lng   | resto_name 
--------+---------+------------
 12.345 | 12.3555 | abc
(1 row)
```

Perhaps you managed to fix it when transcribing your question here?

Seeing that you're storing spatial data, are you also aware of Vertica's support for OGC spatial data types? See here for some details:

https://my.vertica.com/docs/9.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/Geospatial/GeospatialAnalytics/WorkingWithSpatialObjectsInTables.htm%3FTocPath%3DAnalyzing%2520Data%7CGeospatial%2520Analytics%7CWorking%2520with%2520Spatial%2520Objects%2520in%2520Tables%7C_____0

Using Vertica's geospatial support would enable you easily find all of the points within a specific radius, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This should create a table like you are trying to

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE geo_raw(lat float, lng float, resto_name varchar) on commit preserve rows;
INSERT INTO geo_raw(lat, lng, resto_name)VALUES (12.345, 12.3555, 'abc');
SELECT * FROM geo_raw
```

You may need to run each line individually.